# htaccess redirect when URL contain Brackets on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, brackets

I need to convert old hosting site URL where they contain (pid) eg 
/reviews/(pid)/*
where * is a 5 digit unknown number eg 88326
to
/reviews/

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/reviews\/\\(pid\\)\/(.*)$ \/reviews\/ [R=301,L]
```

It is a wordpress site so not sure if that is a reason its not working.

Comment: got it working with this
RewriteRule ^(.*)reviews/(.*)\(pid\)/(.*)$ $1reviews/ [R=301,L]
Didn't have to put a \ in front of the / that seem to have cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When mass changing URLs in WordPress, I often use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) handy plugin.

## Velvet Blues Update URLs

**FEATURES:**

> Users can choose to update links embedded in content, excerpts, or custom fields
>
> Users can choose whether to update links for attachments
>
> View how many items were updated

**USAGE:**

> Using this plugin is very simple. Once it has been activated, navigate
> to Tools -> Update URLs and follow the instructions. Please Note:
> Changes are irreversible. If you haven’t used this plugin before,
> please backup your website before proceeding.

---

**Example Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: our issue is we have moved CMS systems so the old and new url are the same but the path is either removed or slightly different.